# Must Always Run From Terminal - No Way to Make Favorite

Tags: thunderbird

Installed latest TB from TB web site as user "dave" (that's me and only user).  All works fine, email accounts, etc.  However, I can only start TB by opening terminal then typing ~/thunderbird/thunderbird  Which starts TB.  Closing terminal results in TB closing.  Not possible to right click "favorite" in taskbar nor able to move TB icon up or down on bar.  TB does not appear in the SNAP area either where all installed programs are located.  My question is how to go back to the way TB was before I had to reinstall.

Comment: not great workaround, but you could make a shell script that runs Thunderbird, and favorite that script.   Then change the icon to Thunderbird too if you want

Comment: `~/thunderbird/thunderbird`  Which starts TB. Closing terminal results in TB closing. Add a space and a `&`  behind it and it will keep running when you close the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Applications installed using Software, `apt get` or `snap` automatically will install an entry (icon) in the Applications overview for you.

You manually installed Thunderbird. Accordingly you also need to install a launcher to appear in the applications menu yourself. A launcher (.desktop)  may actually come with your download. Then just move that into the appropriate location (`.local/share/applications` for your user only, `usr/share/applications` if access is needed for all users). If no `.desktop` file is provided, then you can make your own. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand), you can see how to create a launcher.

A correct launcher located in either folder will automatically appear in your Application overview, from where you can pin it to the launcher.

*Some more detail*

With thanks to Rinzwind, you will find the launcher of Thunderbird that is shipped with Ubuntu. The only change you likely will need, is on the `Exec=` line. Substitute the correct path for your executable, i.e., `Exec=/home/<yourlogin>/thunderbird/thunderbird %u`. Substitute `<yourlogin` with yoru actual login. Launchers (likely) do not expand `~` to your home directory, so you need to provide the full pathname.

Your icon theme probably will include a thunderbird icon. However, if the launcher appears with a generic icon, you can specify your own icon on the  `Icon=` line.

---

Thunderbird desktop launcher:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Mozilla Thunderbird Mail/News
Comment=Read/Write Mail/News with Mozilla Thunderbird
GenericName=Mail Client
Exec=/usr/bin/thunderbird %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=thunderbird
Categories=Application;Network;Email;
MimeType=message/rfc822;x-scheme-handler/mailto;
StartupNotify=true
Name[es]=Cliente de correo y noticias Thunderbird
Name[cs]=Poštovní klient Thunderbird
Name[ca]=Client de correu Thunderbird
Name[fi]=Thunderbird-sähköposti
Name[fr]=Messagerie Thunderbird
Name[hu]=Thunderbird levelezőkliens
Name[pl]=Klient poczty Thunderbird
Name[pt_BR]=Cliente de E-mail Thunderbird
Name[sv]=E-postklienten Thunderbird
Comment[es]=Lea y escriba correos y noticias con Mozilla Thunderbird
Comment[ca]=Llegiu i escriviu correu
Comment[cs]=Čtení a psaní pošty
Comment[de]=Emails lesen und verfassen
Comment[fi]=Lue ja kirjoita sähköposteja
Comment[fr]=Lire et écrire des courriels
Comment[hu]=Levelek írása és olvasása a Thunderbirddel
Comment[it]=Leggere e scrivere email
Comment[ja]=メールの読み書き
Comment[pl]=Czytanie i wysyłanie e-maili
Comment[pt_BR]=Ler e escrever suas mensagens
Comment[sv]=Läs och skriv e-post
GenericName[hu]=Levelezőkliens
```

(add more languages if yours is not in there ;) ) Install it at `/usr/share/applications/`.

Comment: mind if I add one? :)